# ImportError: libmpi.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, mpi4py

I want to load a custom Python module `dataloader`, which utilizes the `mpi4py` library. My code raises `ImportError: libmpi.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

**Traceback error:**

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last) /tmp/ipykernel_10920/2839973880.py in <module>

> ----> 6 from whole_slide_cnn.dataloader import WholeSlideDataloader, MILDataloader
> 
> ~/CODEX/whole-slide-cnn/whole_slide_cnn/dataloader.py in <module>
> ----> 3 from mpi4py import MPI
> 
> ImportError: libmpi.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such
> file or directory
```

**Jupyter notebook**

```
! conda install -c conda-forge mpi4py
from whole_slide_cnn.dataloader import WholeSlideDataloader, MILDataloader
```

**whole_slide_cnn.dataloader.py**

```
from mpi4py import MPI

class WholeSlideDataloader(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(
        self, 
        dataset,
        augment,
        shuffle,
        num_classes,
        batch_size=1,
        snapshot_path=None,
        hvd=None,
    ):
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.augment = augment
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.snapshot_path = snapshot_path
        self.hvd = hvd

        self._reinit_shuffle_list()

    def __len__(self):
        num_workers = self.hvd.size() if self.hvd != None else 1
        return len(self.dataset) // self.batch_size // num_workers

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        begin_idx = idx * self.batch_size
        end_idx = (idx + 1) * self.batch_size

        x_batch = []
        y_batch = []
        for shuffle_list_idx in range(begin_idx, end_idx):
            dataset_idx = self.shuffle_list[shuffle_list_idx]
            loaded = False
            while not loaded:
                try:
                    img, label = self.dataset[dataset_idx]
                    loaded = True
                except Exception as e:
                    print(traceback.format_exc())
                    print(
                        "Error occurs while loading {} . Retry after 5 seconds.".format(
                            self.dataset.get_slide_path(dataset_idx)
                        )
                    )
                    time.sleep(5)

            if self.augment:
                if img.size < 4 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024:
                    img = _get_augmentor().augment_image(img)
                else:
                    # If the image is too large, imgaug will fail on affine transformation. Use PIL instead.
                    img = _get_augmentor_wo_affine().augment_image(img)
                    img = Image.fromarray(img)
                    angle = np.random.uniform(0.0, 360.0)
                    translate = tuple(np.random.randint(-220, 220, size=[2]))
                    img = img.rotate(angle, resample=Image.NEAREST, translate=translate, fillcolor=(255, 255, 255))
                    img = np.array(img)

            if self.snapshot_path != None:
                os.makedirs(self.snapshot_path, exist_ok=True)
                img_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
                cv2.imwrite(
                    os.path.join(self.snapshot_path, "dataloader_snapshot.tiff"),
                    img_bgr,
                )

            img = preprocess_input(img)
            y = np.zeros(shape=[self.num_classes])
            y[label] = 1.0
            
            x_batch.append(img)
            y_batch.append(y)

        return np.array(x_batch), np.array(y_batch)

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self._reinit_shuffle_list()

    def get_slide_path(self, idx):
        dataset_idx = self.shuffle_list[idx]
        return self.dataset.get_slide_path(dataset_idx)

    def get_y_true(self, idx):
        dataset_idx = self.shuffle_list[idx]
        return self.dataset.get_y_true(dataset_idx)

    def get_dataset_idx(self, idx):
        return self.shuffle_list[idx]

    def _reinit_shuffle_list(self):
        self.shuffle_list = np.arange(len(self.dataset))
        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.shuffle_list)
        if self.hvd != None:
            self.shuffle_list = MPI.COMM_WORLD.bcast(self.shuffle_list, root=0)

            num_workers = self.hvd.size()
            rank = self.hvd.rank()
            self.shuffle_list = [
                self.shuffle_list[idx * num_workers + rank]
                for idx in range(len(self))
            ]


class MILDataloader(WholeSlideDataloader):
    MIL_WHITE_THRESHOLD = 220
    MIL_EM_GAUSSIAN_KERNEL_SIZE = 3
    MIL_EM_P1 = 0.1
    MIL_EM_P2 = 0.05

    def __init__(
        self, 
        dataset,
        augment,
        shuffle,
        num_classes,
        mil_model,
        batch_size=1,
        snapshot_path=None,
        hvd=None,
        mil_patch_size=[224, 224],
        mil_infer_batch_size=32,
        mil_use_em=False,
        mil_k=1,
        mil_skip_white=True,
    ):
        super(MILDataloader, self).__init__(
            dataset=dataset,
            augment=augment,
            shuffle=shuffle,
            num_classes=num_classes,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            snapshot_path=snapshot_path,
            hvd=hvd,
        )
        self.mil_model = mil_model
        self.mil_patch_size = mil_patch_size
        self.mil_infer_batch_size = mil_infer_batch_size
        self.mil_use_em = mil_use_em
        self.mil_k = mil_k
        self.mil_skip_white = mil_skip_white
            
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        x_batch_wsi, y_batch_wsi = super(MILDataloader, self).__getitem__(idx)

        x_batch = []
        y_batch = []
        for i in range(self.batch_size):
            x = x_batch_wsi[i]
            y = y_batch_wsi[i]

            num_patch_y = x.shape[0] // self.mil_patch_size[1]
            num_patch_x = x.shape[1] // self.mil_patch_size[0]

            mil_infer_dataset = []
            coords = []
            for i in range(num_patch_y):
                for j in range(num_patch_x):
                    sliced_x = x[
                        i * self.mil_patch_size[1]: (i + 1) * self.mil_patch_size[1],
                        j * self.mil_patch_size[0]: (j + 1) * self.mil_patch_size[0],
                        :,
                    ]
                    if (
                        self.mil_skip_white and 
                        np.min(sliced_x) > preprocess_input(self.MIL_WHITE_THRESHOLD)
                    ):
                        continue
                    mil_infer_dataset.append(sliced_x)
                    coords.append((j, i))
            mil_infer_dataset = np.array(mil_infer_dataset)

            mil_infer_res = []
            for begin_idx in range(0, len(mil_infer_dataset), self.mil_infer_batch_size):
                end_idx = np.minimum(len(mil_infer_dataset), begin_idx + self.mil_infer_batch_size)
                mil_infer_res.append(
                    self.mil_model.predict_on_batch(
                         mil_infer_dataset[begin_idx: end_idx]
                    )
                )
            mil_infer_res = np.concatenate(mil_infer_res, axis=0)
            benign_rate = mil_infer_res[:, 0]

            if not self.mil_use_em:
                top_k_indices = np.argsort(benign_rate)[0: self.mil_k]
                for index in top_k_indices:
                    x_batch.append(mil_infer_dataset[index])
                    y_batch.append(y)
            else:
                res_map = np.zeros([num_patch_y, num_patch_x, self.num_classes - 1]) # Excluding non-cancer
                for i in range(len(mil_infer_res)):
                    res = mil_infer_res[i]
                    coord = coords[i]
                    res_map[coord[1], coord[0], :] = res[1: ]

                res_map_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(
                    res_map, 
                    (self.MIL_EM_GAUSSIAN_KERNEL_SIZE, self.MIL_EM_GAUSSIAN_KERNEL_SIZE),
                    0
                )

                mil_infer_res_blurred = []
                for i in range(len(mil_infer_res)):
                    coord = coords[i]
                    res_blurred = res_map_blurred[coord[1], coord[0], :]
                    mil_infer_res_blurred.append(res_blurred)
                mil_infer_res_blurred = np.array(mil_infer_res_blurred)

                thres_p1 = np.percentile(mil_infer_res_blurred, 100.0 - self.MIL_EM_P1)

                select = None
                for class_id in range(1, self.num_classes):
                    candidates = mil_infer_res_blurred[:, class_id - 1].tolist()
                    if self.hvd != None:
                        candidates = MPI.COMM_WORLD.gather(candidates, root=0)
                        candidates = MPI.COMM_WORLD.bcast(candidates, root=0)
                        flatten = []
                        for candidate in candidates:
                            flatten += candidate
                        candidates = flatten
                    candidates = np.array(candidates)

                    thres_p2 = np.percentile(candidates, 100.0 - self.MIL_EM_P2)
                    thres = np.minimum(thres_p1, thres_p2)

                    if select is None:
                        select = mil_infer_res_blurred[:, class_id - 1] > thres
                    else:
                        select = np.logical_or(select, mil_infer_res_blurred[:, class_id - 1] > thres)

                no_selected = True
                for i in range(len(mil_infer_res_blurred)):
                    is_select = select[i]
                    if is_select:
                        x_batch.append(mil_infer_dataset[i])
                        y_batch.append(y)
                        no_selected = False

                if no_selected:
                    x_batch.append(mil_infer_dataset[np.argmin(benign_rate)])
                    y_batch.append(y)

        x_batch = np.array(x_batch) # The batch dimension is large as (self.batch_size * self.mil_k).
        y_batch = np.array(y_batch)

        if self.snapshot_path != None:
            os.makedirs(self.snapshot_path, exist_ok=True)
            img = inverse_preprocess_input(x_batch[0])
            img_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
            cv2.imwrite(
                os.path.join(self.snapshot_path, "mil_top_patch_snapshot.tiff"),
                img_bgr,
            )

        return x_batch, y_batch
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, in Anaconda 2021-11 and using `mpi4py` version  3.1.3 (installed via conda-forge) I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
    from Utils.mpi import *
  [..]
    from mpi4py import MPI
ImportError: libmpi.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

but it used to work under an older Anaconda version. Seem that there is a mismatch between installed mpi library versions (`libmpi.so.40`) and the version wanted by `mpi4py`.

Looking for version 12 does not give me a hint of what to do

```
$ find / -iname 'libmpi.so.*' 2>/dev/null 
find / -iname 'libmpi.so.*' 2>/dev/null 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.40.20.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40.20.3
/home/xxx/.conda/pkgs/openmpi-4.0.2-hb1b8bf9_1/lib/libmpi.so.40
/home/xxx/.conda/envs/myy5/lib/libmpi.so.40
/home/xxx/.conda/envs/myy5/lib/libmpi.so.40.20.2
/opt/anaconda-2021.11/pkgs/mpich-3.3.2-hc856adb_0/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.8
/opt/anaconda-2021.11/pkgs/mpich-3.3.2-hc856adb_0/lib/libmpi.so.12
```

..that is, there is a `libmpi.so.40`, some in user installed conda paths (`.conda/pkgs' and` .conda/envs') and a correct version in the system path for my anaconda 2021-11 setup

`/opt/anaconda-2021.11/pkgs/mpich-3.3.2-hc856adb_0/lib/libmpi.so.12`

However, beforehand I tried both a pip and conda install of `mpi4py` (and conda install both systemwide and in the myy5 environment)...so conclusion is a bit tricky here.

The neede library `libmpi.so.12` found in `/opt/anaconda-2021.11/pkgs/mpich` is still not found and loaded, when running Anaconda but a manual soft-link in

`/opt/anaconda-2021.11/lib`

as

```
$ cd /opt/anaconda-2021.11/lib 
$ sudo ln -s /opt/anaconda-2021.11/pkgs/mpich-3.3.2-hc856adb_0/lib/libmpi.so.12
```

could be a temporary solution with the caveat, that the versions 12 and 40 may not be 100% compatible...

It used to work in my older setup , the version-12 error is new for me (or I forgot any hack applied earlier to make it work...)